# REST APIs to demonstrate borrowed books and users from library

Tags: rest, resources, api-design, naming

I have two resources `Books` and `Users`, quite simple. However I need to design or make APIs for the following requirements:

- Find all users who at least have one book took out
- Find still valid users who didn't have any book from the library
- Users who took out a book on given date
- All books that are taken by a given user on a given date
- All books that are still available to be taken

I don't know which way to go now. Put books inside the user or user inside books, or just treat all of that as their separate distinct endpoints/resources.

It's quite a simple thing but I'm struggling to come up with a valid and good naming convention/strategy here with APIs. This is what I struggle with REST sometimes as compared to RPC calls. Is there any guide that provides pointers on what to do in such cases?